# Replacing a character of an element in ArrayList of Strings

Tags: vb.net

I have an ArrayList of strings and I'm trying to replace a character at a randomly generated position in each string, based on the chance of MutationRate.

```
    Dim NewGeneration As New ArrayList 'ArrayList of strings
    For i = 0 To Parents.Count - 1
        NewGeneration.Add(Parents(i))
    Next

    Dim MutationRate As Double = 0.02
    Dim RndNum As New Random()
    Dim MutationPosition As Integer
    Randomize()
    MutationPosition = Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * Len(Target))

    For i = 0 To NewGeneration.Count - 1
        If (Rnd() * 1) <= MutationRate Then
        'Replace character at MutationPosition in NewGeneration(i) with GenerateChar(RndNum As Random)
        End If
    Next

Function GenerateChar(RndNum As Random) As String
    Dim LegalCharacters As String = " abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz"
    Dim Builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim Ch As Char

    Ch = LegalCharacters(RndNum.Next(0, LegalCharacters.Length))
    Builder.Append(Ch)

    Return Builder.ToString()
End Function
```

I've only found functions which replace a specified character as opposed to replacing in a specific position of an element. What can I use to solve this?

EDIT:

Found a solution:

```
    For i = 0 To NewGeneration.Count - 1
        Dim MutationPosition1 As Integer
        Dim MutationPosition2 As Integer
        MutationPosition1 = Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * Len(Target))
        MutationPosition2 = Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * Len(Target))
        If (Rnd() * 1) <= MutationRate Then
            Dim Position1Char As String = GetChar(NewGeneration(i), MutationPosition1)
            NewGeneration(i) = NewGeneration(i).Replace(Position1Char, GenerateChar(RndNum))

            Dim Position2Char As String = GetChar(NewGeneration(i), MutationPosition2)
            NewGeneration(i) = NewGeneration(i).Replace(Position2Char, GenerateChar(RndNum))
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Remember that a string is an array of char's.

Comment: Uhm `ArrayList` of strings? `Randomize`, `Rnd`, `Len`, `GetChar`, `Replace`? Are you sure this is vb.net?

Comment: Why shouldn't be vb.net?

Comment: [Randomize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [Rnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [Len](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxsw58z6(v=vs.90).aspx), [GetChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.getchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: All those functions is part of the *Microsoft.VisualBasic* assembly, not the base class library. They were added to make the migration of old VB6 code (hence my question) to VB.Net easier. The .net equivalent is (...)

Comment: [Random Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx), [String.Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx), [String.Chars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.110).aspx) and [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, the strongly typed [List(T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) class were introduced in .net 2.0 (2005). So, at that point an ArrayList of string  became a `List(Of String)`.

Comment: @nelek Read my previous comments.